# how to pass Json like this in Java

Tags: java, json

I have following Json. please help me to get all component by Java.

```
{
    "Result":{
        "results":2,
        "tags":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"かわいい",
                "weight":34
            },
            {
                "id":4,
                "name":"すっぴん",
                "weight":12
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+json+parser and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+json+parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Map called `json`.

Create a Map called `result` and insert it into `json`, using the key "Result".

Insert the value `2` into `result`, using the key "results".

Create a List, call it `tags`, and insert it into `result` using the key "tags".

Create a Map, call it `tagEntry`.

Insert the key/value pairs "id":1, "name":"かわいい", and "weight":34 into `tagEntry`

Insert `tagEntry` into `tags`.

Repeat the last 3 steps for the second `tagEntry` value.  (Be sure to create a *new* `tagEntry` Map.)

Serialize `json` into a JSON string.

(Or did you want to go the other way?  If so, just do essentially the opposite.)

Answer (score 3):

use the following two model classes, and map it with the JSONObject class.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Result")
public class Result {

    int results;
    List<Tags> tags;

    public int getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(int results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
    public List<Tags> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    public void setTags(List<Tags> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    }



import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="tags")
public class Tags {

    int id;
    String name;
    int weight;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

Then use the following code, basically you have to take the json body and assign it into a json object. Then assign it to a model class

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {


        //Result result = new Result();
        String jsonBody ="  {    \"Result\":{        \"results\":2,        \"tags\":[            {                \"id\":1,                \"name\":\"fghgf\",                \"weight\":34            },            {                \"id\":4,                \"name\":\"fghfgh\",                \"weight\":12            }        ]    }} ";

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonBody);

        for (int x = 0; x < jsonObject.getJSONObject("Result").length(); x++) {

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
            jObject.put("Result", jsonObject.getJSONObject("Result"));

            String theType = "class path." + "Result";
            Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(theType);

            Gson converter = new Gson();
            Result result = (Result) converter.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("Result").toString(), theClass);


        }}
    }
```

you have to get the dependencies for the following two imports,

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Comment: your code has been flagged as low quality answer, please provide some explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use a model class and using gson dependency map the json to a class model